# How to export arbitrary segment of video? "Operation Stopped" error when exporting last X seconds of video

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation, avassetexportsession, avmutablecomposition

The goal is to export an arbitrary segment of some video (e.g., middle third, last half), but `AVAssetExportSession` only succeeds if the starting point is the start of the video.

If `cmStartTime` is not 0, `AVAssetExportSession` fails with this error:

> Failed: Optional(Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11841
>   "Operation Stopped" UserInfo=0x175872d00
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=Operation Stopped,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=The video could not be composed.}).

```
    // Create main composition & its tracks
    let mainComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    let compositionVideoTrack = mainComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
    let compositionAudioTrack = mainComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))

    // Get source video & audio tracks
    let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: fileURL)
    let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: videoURL, options: nil)
    let sourceVideoTrack = videoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]
    let sourceAudioTrack = videoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)[0]

    // Define time values for video
    let timescale = Int32(600)
    let cmStartTime = CMTimeMake(Int64(CGFloat(0.5) * CGFloat(timescale)), timescale)
    let cmEndTime = CMTimeMake(10, 1)
    let timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(cmStartTime, cmEndTime)

    // Add source tracks to composition
    do {
        try compositionVideoTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, ofTrack: sourceVideoTrack, atTime: cmStartTime)
        try compositionAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, ofTrack: sourceAudioTrack, atTime: cmStartTime)
    } catch {
        printError("Error with insertTimeRange while exporting video: \(error)")
    }

    // Create video composition
    let renderSize = compositionVideoTrack.naturalSize
    let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    videoComposition.renderSize = renderSize
    videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(Int64(1), Int32(frameRate))

    // Add layer instruction to video composition
    ...

    // Apply effects to video
    ...

    // Define export URL
    let exportPath = getUniqueTempPath(gMP4File)
    let exportURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: exportPath)

    // Create exporter
    let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mainComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)!
    exporter.videoComposition = videoComposition
    exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
    exporter.outputURL = exportURL
    exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    exporters.append(exporter)

    // Export video
    exporter.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler() {
        // Finish stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arose from not understanding `CMTimeRangeMake` and `insertTimeRange`.

The second value of `CMTimeRangeMake` should be the clip duration, not the end time. So if your start time is the 5 second mark, and the clip lasts 10 seconds, the second value should be 10, not 15.

The `atTime` parameter of `insertTimeRange` should be `kCMTimeZero` since the goal is to create a new clip. In other words, this value says where in *the new track* to insert the clip from the source track.